# Error creating barchart in dc.js

Tags: javascript, html, dc.js

I'm trying to create a barchart in dc.js, I have defined a dimension and a grouping,  and declared a chart type, however I have an error in my Javascript

```
    var dep_var_dimension = ndx.dimension(function ( data ){
      return data.dep_var
    });

    var dep_var_grouping = dep_var_dimension.group()
      .reduceCount(function ( data ) { return data.dep_var });

var monthlsales = dc.barChart('#monthlysales-chart');

  monthlsales
   .width(900).height(900)
   .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
   .dimenson(dep_var_dimension)
   .group(dep_var_grouping)
   .transitionDuration(500)
   .gap(65)
   .filter([3, 5])
   .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0.5, 7.5]))
   .elasticY(true)
   .xAxis().tickFormat();

monthlsales.render();
```

However this is not working, the browser doesn't recognise that my chart is a chart, giving me error:

```
TypeError: monthlsales.width(...).height(...).margins(...).dimenson is not a function
```

I'm very new to Javascript so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you missed "i" in "dimens**i**on" here:

```
... 
monthlsales
   .width(900).height(900)
   .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40})
   .dimenson(dep_var_dimension)
   .group(dep_var_grouping)
...
```

so, `.dimension(dep_var_dimension)` would work like a charm.